# populate treeview from database in windows forms

Tags: c#, sql-server, winforms

(database name - Nav2008r2) having 139 tables and n-multiple number of fields in each table. looking for Parent node as table name & Child node as Field names in treeview

Comment: So? How did you tried to solve it?

Comment: i am able to achieve only table name in form-treeview. i am using this:                                       for (i = 0; i <= ds.Tables[0].Rows.Count - 1; i++)
                {
                    treeView1.Nodes.Add(ds.Tables[0].Rows[i].ItemArray[0].ToString());
                                
                }